# Calendar/Scheduler C#/ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a calendar/scheduler control but have no idea what the best way to go about it. The problem I am having is how to display the data.

What I want to achieve is, Days across the top, i.e Monday Tuesday etc. and then people down the left side with the events showing on each day.

What would be the best way to go about this? I'm using C# and this will be displayed in a web page.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: are third parties an option?  I'd check out something like devexpress before contemplating rolling my own - http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxschedulerdemos/

Comment: Hi NDJ,
Thanks for the link, unfortunately third parties are not an option so would need to create me own.

Comment: then personally I would try to find existing examples with source code as a starting point, it's a big undertaking to start something like this from scratch - a quick google returns controls like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/604401/MVC-Schedule-controls